# Code must find all MP4 files within subdirectory to compress using ffmpeg

Tags: bash, macos, shell, ffmpeg, terminal

I have a drive with a lot of MP4 files which are tough to go through folder by folder and compress.

I'm trying to make a script that runs in terminal that will open a designated folder, find all .mp4 files in the subfolder, and compress the files using specs I designate with ffmpeg. Obviously, the output files should be much lower in size if done right. I'm drafting a code which I have an idea about below but I'm not too good with BASH and/or PERL.

```
for f in $(find ../ -iname '*.avi'); do 
  n=$(echo $f|sed -e 's/.avi/_cbr.mp4/i'); 
  echo "ffmpeg [options] -i $f $n"; 
done
```

output:

```
ffmpeg [options] -i ../1hourjob/videncode/sound10s.avi ../1hourjob/videncode/sound10s_cbr.mp4
ffmpeg [options] -i ../1hourjob/videncode/t003.avi ../1hourjob/videncode/t003_cbr.mp4
ffmpeg [options] -i ../ffmpeg/Masha.avi ../ffmpeg/Masha_cbr.mp4
ffmpeg [options] -i ../ffmpeg/window.avi ../ffmpeg/window_cbr.mp4
```

I'm wondering if I can even make some sort of GUI for this too. I feel a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively traverse the directories in bash like this:

```
avi_to_mp4() {
    cd "$1"
    for f in *; do
        if [[ -d "$f" ]]; then
            avi_to_mp4 "$f"
        elif [[ "$f" == *.avi ]]; then
            newf="${f:0: -4}.mp4"

            echo "$f" to "$newf"     # run your command here

        fi
    done
    cd ..
}

avi_to_mp4 "$1"
```